# How can i measure cpu & memory usage of method in C# code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, profiling

Sorry for my english skill, English is not my mother language.

I want try make server framework, it will be run on my ubuntu server.
I want make remote profiling tools that show cpu and memory usage of each method.

Does C# have profiling classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API is used to profile .NET applications 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/

In two words you need to write unmanaged dll which will be injected into profiled .NET app.